# BUG or Normal Behavior on Android MAC-Address?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to get the MAC address, BSSID and LINK_speed of the Wifi.  I notice that all three show up with values even when Wifi is turned off.  I turn the phone off and then on again but do not turn wifi on.  The app crashes on any interrogation of the three items and I cant try/catch the errors.  If I turn wifi on then off I can interrogate the items and app runs fine. Its like BSSID and LINKSPEED are really 'LAST'BSSID and 'LAST'LINKSPEED. Is being blind to the MAC address after power on but not turning wifi on normal behavior? And is there a way to trap the error to keep from force close of the app?

```
    WifiManager wifi;
    wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    //above work no matter whether wifi on or off before

    String BSSID=wifiInfo.getBSSID();  //<<<<< ERRORS FORCE CLOSE IF NOT EVER CONNECTED
    int WifiLinkSpeed=wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); printi("link speed",WifiLinkSpeed);  
    String MacAddress=wifiInfo.getMacAddress(); Log.e("MAC address",MacAddress);
    //All three of these FORCE close if WIFI has never been turn on
```

Comment: Does full logcat output contains any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) Settings.cntxt.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
strMacAddr = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
if(strMacAddr==null) {
    strMacAddr = "Unknown MAC";
}
```

Comment: It was indeed a NULL and it was erroring out on Log.e("MAC address",MacAddress); Talking with someone they indicated that is Linux normal that the OS is not aware of the MAC address unless you turn on the radio. Under windows its different. LinkSpeed returns -1 if a test needs to be done to show whether wifi has ever been turned on since power up. Corrected code posted below in solution.

Comment: String BSSID=wifiInfo.getBSSID(); 
int WifiLinkSpeed=wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); printi("link speed",WifiLinkSpeed);  //Returns -1 if wifi never been turn on since power up
String MacAddress=wifiInfo.getMacAddress();  
if(MacAddress==null) {MacAddress="0.0.0.0";
Log.e("Unknown MAC address",MacAddress);
}
Log.e("MAC address",MacAddress); //can not be null

Comment: BSSID correction: String BSSID=wifiInfo.getBSSID(); if(BSSID==null)BSSID="unknown";Log.e("BSSID",BSSID);
int WifiLinkSpeed=wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); printi("link speed",WifiLinkSpeed);  //Return -1 if wifi never been turn on since power up
String MacAddress=wifiInfo.getMacAddress();  
if(MacAddress==null) {MacAddress="0.0.0.0";
Log.e("Unknown MAC address",MacAddress);
}
Log.e("MAC address",MacAddress); //can not be null

Answer (score 0):

Although you did say you tried try/catch... which errors/exceptions are you catching?  Evidently not the right one(s).

It's been a while since I did any Android programming, but that's the crux of the matter... figuring out which exception is firing when you try those functions.

```
try {
    // don't declare variables inside block, you'll limit scope
    BSSID=wifiInfo.getBSSID();  //<<<<< ERRORS FORCE CLOSE IF NOT EVER CONNECTED
    WifiLinkSpeed=wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); printi("link speed",WifiLinkSpeed);  
    MacAddress=wifiInfo.getMacAddress(); Log.e("MAC address",MacAddress);
    //All three of these FORCE close if WIFI has never been turn on
}
catch { /* something bad happened, handle it */ }
// continue on since all is good in the world today...
```

Comment: I dont know how to determine what exception is happening. Clues?

Comment: Should be in a log somewhere...  you could just implement a generic exception, catch anything...